# Shall we participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion

By default, this site will be opted into Winter Bash 2014.  For those who are not familiar, here's a summary (courtesy of Jon Ericson):

> Most of you probably remember previous years’ events, but I’ll recap
> anyway, for the newbies among us. Winter Bash is an annual event that
> can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users
> earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous
> to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which
> their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats
> in a leaderboard that looks something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to all sites that choose to
> participate. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra
> features to keep things fresh and exciting.
>
> **Some Details**
>
> This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Users
> will be able to see their entire hat collection on
> [winterbash2014.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com). That site will also have a landing
> page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
> hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
> available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
> will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
> the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

This is a fun event, so I personally recommend that we participate. Please chime in in the answers with your own feelings on the topic. Unless there is a strong anti-hat vibe out there in the ebook world, we will be bustin' out all sorts of weird headgear.

Comment: I'm sure looking forward to it. I really want that beanie.

Comment: Bring on the head gear!

Comment: That winterbash2014 link is no longer online...

Comment: @Daniel The link isn't active yet; it will be when the event starts.

Comment: @EdCottrell oops, my fault - got complete retarded and thought christmas is in 2015. Maybe I need to get back into Future ;)

Comment: @Daniel :) You had a fair point, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I do like those hats, maybe they could bring some more life inhere. (can we award hats for meta.eb activity too?)

Comment: The hat criteria are set by the Stack Exchange staff. As a guess, I'd predict that some of the hats will be awarded for meta activity, some will be available for either main-site or meta activity, and some will have secret criteria (you may not even know the hat exists until somebody earns it).